# Check all words in 'words' collection from DB and check if any words from the text match with any words

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I've got a collection in the database MongoDB called words, which stores all words. They have been extracted via queries on the backend and pushed to the front end.

This has been done in the front end:

```
this.annotationSub = this.annotationService
      .getWordUpdateListener()
      .subscribe((thewords: ComplexWord[]) => {
        this.thewords = thewords;
        this.thewords.map(word => {
          if (word.word === this.setWord) {
            this.wordIWant = word.word;
        }
         console.log(word);
      });
```

The `console.log(word);` on top give these fields =

```
{word: "Lorem", annotation: "Explain Lorem"},
{word: "Aenean", annotation: "Explain Aenean"},
{word: "Hello", annotation: "Explaining Hello"}
```

This retrieves all the text:

```
this.postsService.getPosts();
    this.postsSub = this.postsService
      .getPostUpdateListener()
      .subscribe((posts: Post[]) => {
        this.posts = posts;
        this.posts.map(post => {
          if (post.id === this.id) {
            this.postIWant = post.fileText;
          }
        });
      });
```

On `this.postIWant` I have got all the text from the post.

Now how do I check if any words have any matches with the text in `this.postIWant`?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution.

Passing in the text to the function:

```
function complexWordIdentification(text) {
  const complexWords = ['Hello', 'World', 'Complex Phrase'];
  const results = [];
  let match, regexp, result;

  for (let i = 0; i < complexWords.length; i++) {
    // the complex word we are checking in this iteration
    const complexWord = complexWords[i];
    regexp = new RegExp(complexWord, 'g');

    while ((match = regexp.exec(text)) !== null) {

      result = {
        begin: (regexp.lastIndex - complexWords[i].length),
        end: regexp.lastIndex,
        text: complexWord
      };
      results.push(result);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```